# Как научиться получать данные с сервера в клиентское андроид приложение..?

Tags: php, java, android, xml, веб-программирование

Хочу сделать приложение для сайта.. Но сразу же столкнулся с проблемой.
Нужно чтобы приложение получало текст на странице сайта и виводило его на акран.
Типа как приложение для контактов или одноклассников где приложение читает посты из новостей и виводит текст поста в отдельной рамочке с отдельным оформлением..
Сайт не использует MySql если это важно, только php.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста обучающие материалы по этой теме. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта:

1 На сайте нужно организовать контроллер который будет возвращать к примеру JSON
И принимать его на андроиде проще сделать все по этому туториалу

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/

2 Вариант - использовать Jsoup и парсить странички вот туториал по этому варианту

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Но здесь будет много трудностей с прохождением аутентификации(если такая есть) и надо знать xpath